# Possible to schedule a task to browse to a webpage in an already-open browser?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, task-scheduler

In Windows, I'm trying to schedule a task that visits a predefined webpage every morning before I wake up, but doing so in any *already-open* browser (if there's one available).

I jump between Pale Moon (32-bit) and Cyberfox (64-bit) browsers. Sometimes one's open but not the other. I want to schedule a task that opens a webpage in whichever browser is currently open. If both are already open, then it doesn't matter which. If neither are already open, then it also doesn't matter which. But if one is currently open and not the other, I don't want Task Scheduler to open the other  -- which is what happens when set statically.

For example, if I currently have Pale Moon running (but not Cyberfox), the task would browse to http://example.com in already-open Pale Moon, rather than starting Cyberfox (or whichever browser is set as system default). If Cyberfox is running, but not Pale Moon, the task would instead open the page in Cyberfox. If neither are running, then it doesn't matter which. If both are running, then it doesn't matter which.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a schedule that runs a batch file at specific time of the day. I don't have the batch file but broadly it should have the following:

Check if browser-1 is running, if yes, run browser-1 exe with example.com as the command line parameter and exit

Do similar check for browser-2 and have a default code for handling situation when none of the browsers are running. In that case, chose your preferred browser.

Hope this helps!